# Rails 4 Mailer Issue, Using Multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, actionmailer

I am using 4 models and trying to configure one mailer. I have an `agent` model, a `building` model, a `building_lead` model, and a `building_agent` model. When an end user submits a lead it should trigger a mailer that sends the info to the agents associated with that building. I am coming up short and not sure what I am missing.

building_lead_mailer.rb:

```
class BuildingLeadMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "<help@email.com>"

  def building_lead_notification(agent, building, building_lead, building_agent)
    @agent = agent
    @building = building
    @building_lead = building_lead
    @building_agent = building_agent
    mail(to: @agent.email, subject: "New Building Lead!")
  end
end
```

building_leads_controller:

```
BuildingLeadMailer.building_lead_notification(@agent, @building, @building_lead, @building_agent).deliver_later
```

building_lead_notification.html.erb:

```
Hiya <%= @agent.first_name %>,<br><br>

A lead for <%= @building.primary_address %> has come in. This lead has been distributed to every agent on your building team, so act fast. Their info is below.

Name: <%= @building_lead.name %><br>
Phone: <%= number_to_phone(@building_lead.phone) %><br>
Email: <%= mail_to @building_lead.email %>
Move-In: <%= @building_lead.move_in_date %><br>
Submitted: <%= @building_lead.created_at %>
```

I am getting this error even though there is an email column on the agent table.[image]

Comment: Might be a silly question but is `@agent` defined in the building leads controller? Alternatively you could maybe try passing the `@agent.id`, here, this will tell you if @agent is not defined or not a single record for some reason. Or depending on the object logic, you could create belongs_to / through associations and get all of this data from one object. `@building_lead.building_id`, `@building_lead.agent_id` etc

Comment: @whodini9 agent_id is included in the strong params. Do you mean adding a method for agent in the create section?

Comment: I just mean if a @building_lead references a particular @building or @agent, then you can make an parent/child/sibling association so that you only have to pass one child, rather than passing 4 different models to your mailer. For example in a sports app I could pass only @player to the mailer, and then call `@player.coach.id` or `@player.team.name`. This prevents problems if for some reason `@coach` or `@team` aren't defined in the controller, but if these other models aren't directly related its not a solution. The problem is `@agent` does not exist in your mailer

Comment: `@agent` is `nil`, so it can't respond to `email` method. Show us how are you setting `@agent` in your controller.